# How can I use my Objective-C enum from Swift?

Tags: swift, objective-c

i have an issue bridging my Objective-C enums over to my Swift class and i someone could look at it, i'd be most grateful.

For example, lets say i have an enum like this defined in a MyClass.h file:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, PopupType){
    INFO = 0, QUESTION = 1, WARN = 2
};

.... tons of other stuff
@end
```

i then put that in my bridging header:

```
#import "MyClass.h"
```

but when i try to use it in Swift, either by declaring a variable:

```
let banana : PopupType = .INFO
```

or as a method parameter:

```
func doThingAt(minutes: Int32, popup: PopupType) {
```

i get the error message **Cannot find PopupType in scope.**

another thing it doesn't find in MyClass.h is for example

```
extern int const COLOR_GREEN;
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, your code compiles without problems for me. Does the problem occur in a fresh new project, with only that code present and nothing else?

Comment: no it's a super old project :) so it has tons of stuff that potentially could be wrong. But I do use other swift/objective-c stuff back and forth that works, so it's not the bridging header I think.

Comment: As I said, I cannot reproduce the problem in a fresh project. I would suggest that you try that as well.

Comment: Is the bridging header correctly defined in the target ?